# Unusual mathematical terms

Tags: soft-question, terminology, big-list

From time to time, I come across some unusual mathematical terms. I know something about [strange attractors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor#Strange_attractor). I also know what [Witch of Agnesi](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WitchofAgnesi.html) is. However, what prompted me to write this question is that I was really perplexed when I read the other day about [monstrous moonshine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstrous_moonshine), and this is so far my favorite, out of similar terms.

Some others:

- [Cantor dust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Cantor_dust)
- [Gabriel's Horn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel%27s_Horn) (also known as Torricelli's trumpet)
- [Koch snowflake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake)
- [Knaster–Kuratowski fan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan) (also known as Cantor's leaky tent or Cantor's
  teepee depending on the presence or absence of the apex; there is also Cantor's leaki*er* tent)

Are there more such unusual terms in mathematics?

---

*Jan 17 update:* for fun, word cloud of all terms mentioned here so far:

[image]

and another, more readable:

[image]

Comment: I've always been tickled by 'Fuzzy Logic.'

Comment: The `Golden ratio' $\phi$.

Comment: It may say more about me than about math, but if I need to give a strange sounding math term, then [perverse sheaves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perverse_sheaf) is my go-to-answer.

Comment: Shouldn't this be CW?

Comment: [Klein's bottle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle)

Comment: @jyrki That one is even worse in Danish due to the choice someone made at some point to translate sheaf as kneppe, rather than neg (which would mean the same but not be slang for a certain verb).

Comment: I tried to downvote, but don't have the required rep yet. Lists of things don't fit well in the Q & A format. Flagging this as a poll.

Comment: I'm surprised that no-one has linked to [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/410/) yet.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to ask for references for all the terms. There are links in many articles, but not all.

Comment: @RubberDuck If you like this, see the [big-list tag](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list).

Comment: @Jefromi if y'all are all right with this and want to go down that road, so be it.

Comment: @RubberDuck Just pointing you at it, didn't say I agreed.  (I'm not a regular user here, just a sometimes-lurker. I'm mainly active on cooking, where this kind of thing would get nuked from orbit.)

Comment: Threesomes, Degenerates, and Love Triangles -> http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.0799

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: the best part being, of course, that they are neither perverse, nor sheaves.

Comment: Wait, you want someone to compile a list of *all* the "unusual" terms in mathematics? Do you believe that someone like that even exists?

Comment: I never said "all", @AsafKaragila. I just have impression that the origin of terms is not explained in many answers (and that can be very interesting part), and also I think there is a need for a  list that covers larger but reasonable number of terms.

Comment: So you want people to write a few sentences describing the history of the terminology, if one even exists, for each suggested term, and you want someone to do it for a lot of terms in a single post?

Comment: Yes, both. All in reasonable limits, of course. The presentation is also important, not only number of terms etc. @AsafKaragila

Comment: For now, @DenDenDo's answer wins.

Comment: I think that you are forgetting that a lot of these terms are rather advance (otherwise, you would have known most of them, and wouldn't have asked this question). This makes things awkward, I don't know many terms from geometry or group theory or graph theory that might be considered "unusual"; and I doubt that many analysts, or category theorists, are aware of the examples I provided (whose history is unbeknown to me). Do you get my point?

Comment: I do, but it is an interesting topic, and someone good at presenting can compile an attractive easy-to-read answer.

Comment: “The question is widely applicable to a large audience. A detailed canonical answer is required to address all the concerns.” what.

Comment: Including anything with "Tits" isn't fair. It's not a funny word in Belgium, and it's the guy's NAME!

Comment: I do not like that type of humor too, but what can you do? It is funny for some people, and it is not MEANT to be an insult to anybody. I think great majority of us visiting this site have enough intellectual tolerance to live with such things... So, my advice is not to be overly sensitive, @MattSamuel.

Comment: Just found another one: [a Killing form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Complex theorems often use simple, illustrative names.
[Ham Sandwich Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_sandwich_theorem)
[No Free Lunch Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem)
[Ugly Duckling Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugly_duckling_theorem)

Some are named by the scenario they are describing
[Birthday Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack)
[Doomsday Argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_argument)

Other by the accompanying real-life events
[Happy Ending Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Ending_problem)

and finally the top 10 Dirty Mathematics from [Spikedmath](http://spikedmath.com/482.html) (slightly edited to take up less space)
[image]
[A Survey on Cox Rings](https://math.berkeley.edu/~velasco/Survey.pdf)
[Cox-Zucker machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox%E2%80%93Zucker_machine)

Comment: Good examples. However, /ˈlɑːtɛx/ is not (should not be) pronounced Lay-tech, that's just typical americanisation of syllables. The fault is with the original poster of the image but it bothers me :)

Comment: @orion How do you pronounce it?

Comment: You have the IPA above ("Lah-tech" is you want, where "tech" rhymes with Scottish "loch"). That's how the entire world says it (pronouncing "a" as "eye" is english-only thing), and that's how it was originally intended. However, due to constant ignorance and abuse, the alternative used above is usually stated as acceptable. The last syllable is also constantly pronounced wrongly, but that's another matter.

Comment: Because [X Makes Anything Cool](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/XMakesAnythingCool)

Comment: @DenDenDo I believe that the X in $\LaTeX$ is actually supposed to be a chi, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @anorton, you are right: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tau_Epsilon_Chi#Pronouncing_and_writing_.22TeX.22 .

Comment: Call me naive, but why is #7 dirty?!

Comment: @rschwieb I think it's intended to sound like "impotent"?

Comment: I know this is comment thread necromancy, but... @orion: Per Lamport, /ˈleɪtɛx/ is perfectly acceptable, as is /ˈlɑːtɛx/.  "One of the hardest things about LaTeX is deciding how to pronounce it.This is also one of the few things I'm not going to tell you about LaTeX, since pronunciation is best determined by usage, not fiat. TeX is usually pronounced teck, making lah-teck, and lay-teck the logical choices; but language is not always logical, so lay-tecks is also possible."  Not simply a crude Americanism, despite your insinuations. :-)

Answer (score 45):

I've always liked 'abstract nonsense'.

To quote [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_nonsense):

> Note that referring to an argument as "abstract nonsense" is not supposed to be a derogatory expression, and is actually often a compliment regarding the generality and sophistication of the argument.

Comment: and don't forget "highly abstract nonsense"

Comment: *General* abstract nonsense.

Comment: ***Special*** abstract nonsense!

Comment: I thought it was "*generalized* abstract nonsense".

Answer (score 32):

[Hairy Ball Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem)

[No Hair Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem)

[Arnold's Cat Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold%27s_cat_map#The_discrete_cat_map) (this kills the cat)

[No Ghost Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goddard%E2%80%93Thorn_theorem)

[The condom/glove problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glove_problem) (do NOT do this)

[Buridan's Ass Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buridan%27s_ass)

Comment: Is Buridan's Ass mathematical? I've heard of it, but never in the context of mathematics.

Comment: Yes, see this paper by Leslie Lamport: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/buridan.pdf

Comment: Whoever came up with the solution to the condom problem has apparently never used a condom.

Comment: When I once told someone of the hairy ball theorem he found it funny that it was discovered by someone named “Harry Ball”.

Comment: no kill cat plz thankyou

Answer (score 31):

I've always been fond the term [pointless topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointless_topology).

Answer (score 23):

While the pronunciation is French, there is the [Tits Group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tits_group).

There's also the [Dragon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_curve) family of fractal curves. Also, related to Cantor dust is the [Menger sponge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_sponge). Actually, fractals give a lot of fun ones, such as [Douady rabbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douady_rabbit) (and related "fat rabbit"), [Mandelbulb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbulb), [Pythagoras Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagoras_tree_(fractal)), the [Flowsnake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowsnake), and the [Minkowski Sausage](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinkowskiSausage.html).

In recreational mathematics, with some applications to number theory, numbers can be [happy](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HappyNumber.html) or [sad/unhappy](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnhappyNumber.html); [evil](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EvilNumber.html) or [odious](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OdiousNumber.html); [economical](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EconomicalNumber.html), [equidigital](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EquidigitalNumber.html), or [wasteful](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WastefulNumber.html); or [lucky](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LuckyNumber.html). **Edit**: They can also be [solitary](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SolitaryNumber.html) or [friendly](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FriendlyNumber.html), which made me think of [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/410/).

Computability theory has [Busy Beavers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver).

So, "Are there more such unusual terms in mathematics?" **Yes.**

Comment: As a colleague of mine likes to point out, changing the pronunciation from 'tits' to 'teats' just substitutes a different name for the same thing(s), so it's not clear that it makes it less risqué.

Answer (score 20):

I always wanted to get a room at the [Hilbert Hotel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel).

I also love working with [annihilators](http://www.math.ku.edu/~mandal/math790/annihilator.pdf)....

Comment: All of our rooms are occupied... How long will you be staying?

Comment: That's a shame because I have an infinite amount of millionaire friends who wanted to dine at the restaurant....

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven Countable or uncountable? Are they drinking beer? Do they know their limits?

Comment: @flawr, well, countable of course.  Actually, the first mathematician will order a pint of beer, the second will order a half a pint, the third will order a quarter of a pint...so if the bartender is smart,....

Answer (score 20):

A [Killing field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_vector_field) is not as bloody as it sounds; it's actually a certain type of vector field named after Wilhelm Killing.

Comment: And the Killing form https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form , named after the same gentleman.

Answer (score 13):

Here's my favorite: [cleavage](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cleavage) (SFW).

Comment: The URL contains "show/cleavage". That in and of it self felt like a risky click. Alas, disappointed at the safety of it.

Comment: @Axoren How is “cleavage” ever a risky click?

Comment: When you're at work.

Comment: @Axoren Added a SFW tag.

Answer (score 13):

The function $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}\frac{1}{q}&:&x\in\mathbb{Q}\text{ and }x=\frac{p}{q}\text{ in lowest terms}\\0&:&x\notin \mathbb{Q}\end{array}\right.$$ is called ([among other things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function)) the **Stars over Babylon**.

Comment: The popcorn / Christmas-tree function!

Answer (score 13):

While categories are often called "Cats", in set theory we have mice and weasels.

(We also have morasses, which sound pretty weird, but one look at the definition and you see that the name is very accurate in describing the object.)

I recently sat in a lecture where someone defined a "piste" (ski slope).

Comment: And premice! (Or is there another phrase for those now?)

Answer (score 13):

The [Chicken McNugget Theorem](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Chicken_McNugget_Theorem).

Comment: Hilarious name indeed! Could not resist myself from sharing it in my Facebook.

Comment: Numberphile did a video on this, IIRC.

Answer (score 12):

[The monster group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_group)
A group with $808017424794512875886459904961710757005754368000000000$ elements.

Comment: An article about them in Scientific American was titled "The capture of the monster".

Comment: Do not forget the *Baby Monster Group*.

Answer (score 12):

The [Hairy Ball theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem) and [forgetful functors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forgetful_functor) make me giggle!

Comment: What did the forgetful functor do for her stoner friend? She left a joint as a free object!

Answer (score 11):

Diagram chasing is rather fun.

Comment: Adding a link for those who were not aware of this term: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_diagram#Diagram_chasing

Answer (score 11):

The concept of a [Syzygy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syzygy_(mathematics)) always tickled me, as do [Zero-Knowledge Proofs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof). Of course I'd be remiss were I not to mention [Gropes](http://www.ams.org/notices/200408/what-is-teichner.pdf).

Answer (score 10):

Alien Ring Structure - from Mochizuki's papers on inter-universal Teichmuller theory.

Comment: That stuff looks Alien to me.

Answer (score 9):

Would you like to [zigzag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fence_%28mathematics%29) inside the [random forest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest) of some beautiful 
[tropical geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_geometry)? But keep an eye on voracious [ant colonies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms)!

[image: Tropical cubic curve]

(The image shows a tropical cubic curve, stolen from Wikipedia.)

Answer (score 8):

[Exotic spheres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere) (differentiable manifolds which are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic to an $n$-sphere).

The [Alexander horned sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere) (this shows the [Jordan–Schönflies theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem) doesn't hold in $3$ dimensions).

Answer (score 8):

[Devil's staircase](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DevilsStaircase.html)

[Blancmange function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BlancmangeFunction.html)

Answer (score 8):

Not exactly math, but physics is close enough. There are higher derivative of velocity called [jerk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_%28physics%29), [jounce, snap, crackle and pop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jounce).

And there's also [screw theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_theory).

Answer (score 7):

Although the term may not really be in common use: A paper about ["Generalized staircases: Recurrence and symmetry"](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.3736.pdf) refers to a figure showing a certain surface at page 10, and calls it

"**The eierlegende Wollmilchsau surface**"

The term [eierlegende Wollmilchsau](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eierlegende_Wollmilchsau) literally means "egg-laying wool-milk-sow", and refers to any (usually imaginary) thing that "can do everything" or "has many positive properties". In this case, the surface has many properties that usually are not found in this combination in other surfaces.

Answer (score 6):

Some examples could be:

- [Dessin d'enfant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dessin_d%27enfant) (child's drawing).
- [Germ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germ_(mathematics))
- [Skyscraper sheaf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalk_%28sheaf%29#Skyscraper_sheaf)
- [Salt and pepper function](http://www.mecca.org/~halfacre/MATH/Salt%20and%20Pepper.pdf)
- Nuclear topology
- Radon measures
- Polish spaces

Answer (score 6):

The famous "pons asinorum" (Euclid's Elements, Book I, prop. 5), which literally means "bridge of asses (donkeys)" in Latin.

Pascal's limaçon curve (French for snail).

Another mathematical term that I find peculiar is "totient" (as in the Euler $\phi$-function. Apparently, it was first introduced by J. J. Sylvester.

Comment: Couldn't you also translate that as "bridge of asses"? Or "ass-bridge"? That's much more fun.

Comment: Sure, an ass is a donkey after all. :-)

Comment: Sylvester invented all kinds of strange mathematical words: _syzygy_ (mentioned above), _catalecticant_, _cumulant_, _cyclotomic_, etc.

Answer (score 6):

There are topological spaces called [hedgehog spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedgehog_space).  According to the linked Wikipedia article, a $K$-hedgehog space is sometimes said to have "spininess $K$."

And let's not forget the process of [blowing up points on a plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowing_up#The_blowup_of_a_point_in_a_plane).

Comment: Talking about your research may get you in trouble: http://mathoverflow.net/a/53738/48859

Answer (score 5):

Graph Theory has its ["snarks"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snark_(graph_theory)).

Comment: What about grumpkins?

Answer (score 5):

Be sure to check out wikipedia's [List of humorous units of measurement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_humorous_units_of_measurement), with such gems as:

> Helen of Troy (from the Iliad) is widely known as "the face that launched a thousand ships". Thus, 1 millihelen is the amount of beauty needed to launch a single ship.
>
> A Kardashian is a unit of measure representing 72 days of marriage.
>
> The beard-second is a unit of length inspired by the light-year, but used for extremely short distances such as those in integrated circuits. The beard-second is defined as the length an average beard grows in one second.
>
> The Wheaton is a measurement of Twitter followers relative to celebrity Wil Wheaton. The measurement was standardized when Wil Wheaton achieved half a million Twitter followers, with the effect that Wil Wheaton now has 5.52 Wheatons himself (as of January 2015). As few Twitter users have millions of followers, the milliwheaton (500 followers) is more commonly used.

And also wikipedia's [List of unusual units of measurement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unusual_units_of_measurement).

Comment: This isn't exactly mathematical, as units are characteristic to the natural sciences (i.e., physics) and math can/does do live without.

Comment: It's not exactly non-mathematical, either, as units are quite relevant to mathematics.

Answer (score 4):

For the botanists here: I'd like to add [Euclid's orchard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_orchard) and the [opaque forest problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_forest_problem) which is rather from the field of computer graphics, but still got some maths in it.

EDIT: And of course the [Sexy Primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexy_prime) as well as [wild and tame knots.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_knot)

Answer (score 4):

The [Wiener Sausage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_sausage) is what the nbhd's of a Brownian motion trace out.

One might argue things named after Norbert Wiener or Mark Kac are not unusual since they were relatively famous mathematicians. But its still funny.

Comment: Sorry to be a party-pooper (ahem), but "Kac" is pronounced like "Katz".

Comment: Supposed to be pronounced like Katz. Doesn't mean people pronounce it that way in reality. =)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one from sorting.

- [Stupid Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort).

Answer (score 3):

I've always been fond of [the spectral theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem).

Answer (score 3):

Telling a story on myself. When as a graduate student I first heard about noetherian rings (before I saw a definition) I wanted to know what an ether was, so I could think about a ring that didn't have any of them.

I later taught for a while at Bryn Mawr College, where a colleague used Emmy Noether's desk.

Answer (score 3):

In the Banach space theory there is a property called local unconditional structure, which is l.u.st for short. Another property is the Dunford-Pettis property which is DP for short.

Answer (score 3):

Soap Film Problem - this is actually another term for "minimal surface problems", since soap bubbles or other similar soap forms tend to minimize their surface.

Links [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SinclairsSoapFilmProblem.html) and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinimalSurface.html).

Also, [Antoine's necklace](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AntoinesNecklace.html).

Answer (score 2):

Game theory has a [trembling hand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trembling_hand_perfect_equilibrium),
some [cheap talk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheap_talk), and, collectively, an
[El Farol Bar problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Farol_Bar_problem).

Answer (score 1):

Nice topology tool

- [Alexander's Trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander%27s_trick)

Answer (score 1):

The Tietze Extension Theorem is always a good one, and Heine-Borel if the speaker doesn't have his German pronunciations down.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of [Krylov Subspace Methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krylov_subspace), which I remain convinced are actually ways of detecting cloaked Klingon birds of prey.

Answer (score 1):

The [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)
is an abstract thing given a mundane (concrete) name, not unlike the "snowflake". 
And I've heard that the term [googol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol)
was chosen specifically because it sound funny.

Answer (score 0):

John H. Conway and Simon B. Kochen's **free will theorem**

[Free will theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_will_theorem)

And some theorems/terms named after unusual mathematicians. For example

- [Rice's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem)
- [Stone Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_space)
- [Peano Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_curve)
- [Church's Theorem/Entscheidungsproblem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsproblem)