# Examples of unexpected names of concepts in mathematics

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I was wondering around wikipedia and I found two concepts called "Monstrous moonshine" i.e.

In mathematics, monstrous moonshine, or moonshine theory, is the unexpected connection between the monster group M and modular functions, in particular, the j function. The term was coined by John Conway and Simon P. Norton in 1979.

And then as a consequence "Monster group" i.e.

In the area of modern algebra known as group theory, the Monster group M (also known as the Fischer–Griess Monster, or the Friendly Giant) is the largest sporadic simple group,

So without real need of understanding those concepts, do you guys know any more such concepts with unexpected names? Obviously word "unexpected" has a very subjective meaning so I will leave it for you to decide what such name is. This is purely recreational question, I hope it is fine to post it.

Comment: Look up googology.

Comment: Lookup ill-posed problems, which are in fact well defined and well studied.

Comment: @dxiv Ah yes, I've seen many of those, but never had the real care to try and study them.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1102872/34930

Comment: I did not see that in the search box! Thanks

Comment: Also, [the British flag theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_flag_theorem).

Comment: my favorite is the pumping lemma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.The Ham Sandwich Theorem. 2.Fermat's Last Theorem (It wasn't his last. Fermat  announced some results without proofs. This was the last one anyone else proved.)

Comment: And of course, Fermat's Last Theorem was called that even before it had been proven, despite the fact that at that time it technically wasn't a theorem, but a conjecture.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots, irrational numbers (literally "not ratio"), imaginary numbers, strange attractors, the hairy ball theorem, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I know maybe this is not an unexpected name in English, but here is one that made us giggle all the time: in group theory, there are a class of subgroups called "subnormal". In Spanish (and other romance languages), "subnormal" is a word used as an insult (back in the day it was the standard word for mentally disabled people, now it's very demeaning and it's plainly an insult, like the "R" word). So we studied group theory and one type of groups were always insulted.